# Angular Material expansion panel API in ngFor, how to auto-close

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngfor

I recently added the Angular Material accordion component in my angular project. In the API they use the examples provided for automatically closing the panel: https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples <-- look here (doing `(opened) = panelStateOpen` in the template and specifying the boolean in the component)

I did this but because I'm looping through the information of `menuItems`, have two components, and then injecting my expansion panel, the `panelOpenState` isn't correct.

Right now, I have

```html
<mat-accordion *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems">
  <confmenu menuItem={{menuItem}}></confmenu>
</mat-accordion>
```

In my parent template, and in my confmenu (child template):

```html
<mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState=true" (closed)="panelOpenState=false">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      {{menuItem}}
    </mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description>
      {{menuDescription}}
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select (change)="selectConfig($event.value)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of menuOptions" [value]="option" (click)="selectConfig(option)">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>             
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

in the child's component I have
`panelOpenState = false;`

the ts as a whole is

```js
/** @title Basic menu */
@Component({
  selector: 'confmenu',
  templateUrl: './confmenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confmenu.component.scss']
})
export class ConfigurationMenu implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() menuItem: string;
  panelOpenState = false;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() { 
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    //blank for now
  }

  selectConfig(value:string){
    this.selectedConfig = value;
    this._menuService.changeSelectedConfig(this.selectedConfig);
    this._menuService.populateSelectedConfigConfigurations(this.selectedConfig);
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to make it so that the panels close on click of another panel? Right now, they are all staying open upon clicking another.

Comment: can you show TS file of child component

Comment: @LALITKANTADIBYADARSHAN i edited it

Comment: Are you getting any error in console

Comment: @LALITKANTADIBYADARSHAN , no, i'm not. i don't think that's the issue. i think it's because i have multiple of them, they're in a for loop

Answer (score 2):

Most simple autoclosing with list of items to represent in mat-expansion panel - is to store current opened id of panel item.

component.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
<mat-expansion-panel 
  [expanded]="item.id === currentOpenedItemId" 
  (opened)="handleOpened(item)"
>
</ng-container>
```

component.ts

```
...
currentOpenedItemId: number;

public handleOpened(item): void { 
  this.currentOpenedItemId = item.id;
}
```

also you can set initial value while you got data - to open first panel

Answer (score 1):

use this sample https://stackblitz.com/angular/olmedrdbamo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-steps-example.ts   use *ngFor index for the 'step'

```
<mat-accordion *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems; let index = index">
                <confmenu menuItem={{menuItem}} [index]="index"></confmenu>
  </mat-accordion>
```

add `@Input() index: number;` to the component

and you can adjust that sample like this

```
 <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step === index" (opened)="setStep(index)" hideToggle>
```

Comment: the logic in there makes sense, but it's not working for me -- and no errors in the console. no matter what, my toggles are staying open. 

       ``` <mat-accordion *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems; let index = index">
                <confmenu menuItem={{menuItem}} [index]="index"></confmenu>
           </mat-accordion>```

added what you have above along with the setStep function (and initialized the step variable)

Comment: it looks like panel number is undefined when it goes to setStep? and then get's reset? any ideas?

Comment: did you added `@Input() index: number;`?

Comment: yes i did, which is what is confusing. it's almost like it's not really picking up the change in setStep because it's only temporarily setting it?